# D8 - How to filter months and year in View page

Tags: date, drupal, filter, drupal-8, datefilter

In D7, date field and authoring date can filter by months and year, even days, in 'Filter Criteria'. But in D8, this function seems abolish in 'Filter Criteria'. I keep looking for module that can filter months and years. Group filters obviously isn't a good way to solve this problem.

Anyway, my question is, how to filter days and months programmatically ? In theme_hook, write a module, whatever it's work. Because this filtering function is quite important for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes under **Contextual Filters** now. But you still might need to do some little coding if you want to expose this filter, see https://www.flocondetoile.fr/blog/filter-content-year-views-drupal-8.

[image: Contextual Filters]

Comment: Thanks! The only thing that I don't like is the author didn't explain how to  code the module.

Comment: This worked for me. The only problem is that it does not seem to work for ajax-enabled views. Is there any workaround for this?